# How do limit xml from being displayed using JAXB

Tags: spring, xml-parsing, jaxb, annotations

Using Spring, I'm building a RESTful web service and have an object that is being marshalled (Jaxb2Marshaller), this is tied to MYSQL database that has @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations.  How do I not display the child elements being returned?  Is there some annotation for this?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">UNUSED</title>
  <id></id>
  <updated>2012-12-18T20:54:47.961Z</updated>
  <content type="application/xml">
    <paymentTokenWrapper xmlns="http://www.oclc.org/SampleService">
      <createDate>2012-12-18 15:54:47.848-0500</createDate>
      <expirationTime>2012-12-18 16:14:47.848-0500</expirationTime>
      <payee>
        <id>32</id>
        <name>Vendor Center</name>
        <symbol>CCC</symbol>
        <paymentTokenPayee>41</paymentTokenPayee>
        <paymentTokenPayee>41</paymentTokenPayee>
        <paymentTokenPayee>41</paymentTokenPayee>
        <paymentTokenPayee>41</paymentTokenPayee>
        <paymentTokenPayee>41</paymentTokenPayee>
      </payee>
      <payer>
        <id>41</id>
        <name>OCLC ASIA PACIFIC, JAPAN1</name>
        <symbol>AAJ1</symbol>
        <paymentTokenPayer>41</paymentTokenPayer>
        <paymentTokenPayer>41</paymentTokenPayer>
     </payer>
      <paymentTokenStatus>UNUSED</paymentTokenStatus>
      <principalIDNS>43453241</principalIDNS>
      <spendingLimit>100.00</spendingLimit>
      <tokenUUID>VxsvpDZb6o3SMWz0ZY3OMXaz0DzbKtKXnAN0FkPkTc8MfMSVXy4h0nKf0c9Rldf7V0VzB6MPiWKeHDhu</tokenUUID>
      <updateDate>2012-12-18 15:54:47.848-0500</updateDate>
      <userPrincipalId>754645341</userPrincipalId>
    </paymentTokenWrapper>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlTransient` annotation to prevent a field/property from being marshalled to XML.  Or you can specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on the class and only annotated fields/properties will be marshalled to XML.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/04/jaxb-and-unmapped-properties.html